# Proportionality constant between eigenvectors in 1D free quantum particle

Tags: quantum-mechanics, momentum, hamiltonian, eigenvalue, dirac-delta-distributions

My textbook proposes to find the proportionality constant $\lambda$.
Given a free particle ($V = 0$), we know that the Hamiltonian is
$$\mathcal{H} = \frac{\mathcal{P}^2}{2m}.$$

We know that if $| p \rangle$ is eigenvector of $\mathcal{P}$ it is for $\mathcal{H}$ as well, with eigenvalue $ E = \frac{p^2}{2m}$.

In 1D motion, for any eigenvalue $E$, there are two different values of $p$, so there's the degeneracy of $E$:
$$|p = +\sqrt{2mE} \rangle = \lambda| E, +1 \rangle$$
$$|p = -\sqrt{2mE} \rangle = \lambda| E, -1 \rangle.$$

Textbook asks to find $\lambda$ using the normalization conditions:

$$\langle p | p' \rangle = \operatorname{\delta}(p - p')$$
$$\langle E, \alpha | E', \alpha ' \rangle = \operatorname{\delta}(E - E')\delta_{\alpha\alpha'}.$$

Combined with the delta's properties.
I probably spent too much time on this but I can't figure it out (mainly due to a poor understanding of Delta function). It seems to me this should be a trivial question, but how do I solve this?

Solution should be $\lambda = \sqrt{\frac{p}{m}}$, but I can't seem to simplify the $2$ in $2m$ when substituting from energy (I'm somewhat blindly manipulating algebraically the function, without really grasping what the steps represent).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The proportionality constant follows from the properties of the delta distribution.

**Step 1:**

Substitute the expression of the energy in terms of the momentum in the second orthonormalization relation:
\begin{equation}
\delta(E-E') = \delta\left(\frac{p^2}{2m}- \frac{p'^2}{2m}\right) =\delta\left(g(p)\right)
\end{equation}
Here I am considering the $\delta$ to ''live'' inside of an integration over $E$ with $E'$ being constant. We have to consider the composition of the $\delta$ with the function $g(p) = p^2/2m - p'^2/2m$.

**Step 2:**

We now have to make use of the properties of the $\delta$ which can be found in any book on mathematical methods, namely:
\begin{equation}
\delta(f(x)) = \sum_i\frac{\delta(x-x_i)}{|f'(x_i)|}
\end{equation}
where $f(x_i)=0$. This property can be proved by making a change of variable in the integral where the $\delta$ is to be found. In our case we have:
\begin{equation}
\delta(g(p)) = \frac{\delta(p-p')}{2p'/2m} + \frac{\delta(p+p')}{|2p'/2m|} = \frac{m}{|p'|} \left[\delta(p-p') + \delta(p+p')\right]
\end{equation}
The $|p'|$ in the denominator can be replaced by $|p|$ because integration over the $\delta$ will simply yield the substitution $p'\rightarrow \pm p$ in the rest of the integrand, including the $p'$ in the denominator. Hence
\begin{equation}
\delta(g(p)) = \frac{m}{|p|} \left[\delta(p-p') + \delta(p+p')\right]
\end{equation}

**Step 3:**

We can introduce a new notation for states with positive momentum and states with negative momentum which brings us closer to the rhs. of the equalities above:
\begin{align}
|p=+\sqrt{2mE}\rangle &\equiv |p=\sqrt{2mE}, +1\rangle\\
|p=-\sqrt{2mE}\rangle &\equiv |p=\sqrt{2mE}, -1\rangle\\
\end{align}
And hence
\begin{equation}
\delta(p-p') =  \langle p | p' \rangle = \langle |p|,\alpha | |p'|, \beta \rangle = \delta(|p|-|p'|)\delta_{\alpha, \alpha'}
\end{equation}
which is just saying that the moduli of the momenta have to be equal, as well as the orientations.

In order to make the comparison straightforward, we can further express $\delta(|p|-|p'|)$ as:
\begin{equation}
\delta(|p|-|p'|) = \delta(p-p') + \delta(p+p')
\end{equation}

You can convince yourself that this is the case by simply observing that the first delta is different from zero when $|p|=|p'|$, in other words, $p=\pm p'$. Alternatively, you can see this as a delta composed with the absolute value function, and apply the same property as we used in step 2.

**Step 4:**

We can now compare and deduce the prefactor $\lambda$.
\begin{equation}
\langle p | p'\rangle = \lambda^2 \langle E, \alpha | E', \alpha' \rangle
\end{equation}
Bringing everything together we have:
\begin{equation}
\delta(p-p') = \left[ \delta(p-p') + \delta(p+p') \right]\delta_{\alpha, \alpha'} = \lambda^2 \frac{m}{|p|} \left[\delta(p-p') + \delta(p+p')\right]\delta_{\alpha, \alpha'}
\end{equation}
which automatically implies
\begin{equation}
\lambda = \pm\sqrt{\frac{|p|}{m}}
\end{equation}

---

A poor understanding of the delta distribution is common among ''beginners''. Something I found useful to remember is that the delta function only truly makes sense inside of an integration symbol. Sometimes it is also helpful to mentally replace it by one of the functions that tend to the delta distribution in some limit (i.e. an arbitrarily thin gaussian, lorentzian...).

Comment: Gaaah, thank you, I don't know why but I got stuck in step 2 where I didn't take the derivative of $\operatorname{g}(p)$ while considering the sum. I'll probably go do more exercises about delta before proceeding, so I can build up an intuition. (Plus your answer is so helpful since you wrote every reasoning for the steps). Thank you very much!

Comment: It was my pleasure. Good luck building that intuition!